# response checksum or hash not matching in payumoney?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, payumoney

When notification is passed to the app after payumoney processing it sends response hash and we need to compute the hash and match it with the passed in response hash.

I use the following code to compute the expected response hash.

```
Digest::SHA512.hexdigest([
  PAYU_SALT,
  notification.transaction_status,
  notification.user_defined,
  notification.customer_email,
  notification.customer_first_name,
  notification.product_info,
  notification.gross,
  notification.invoice,
  PAYU_KEY].join("|"))
```

The hash of the following string is computed

```
"salt|success|||||||||||||Payment|100.0|1|key"
```

When I print the following hash it gives

```
Digest::SHA512.hexdigest([
  PAYU_SALT,
  notification.transaction_status,
  notification.user_defined,
  notification.customer_email,
  notification.customer_first_name,
  notification.product_info,
  notification.gross,
  notification.invoice,
  PAYU_KEY].join("|"))  

  #⇒ e7b3c5ba00b98aad9186a5e6eea65028a[...]
```

whereas `notification.checksum` gives

```
  #⇒ 546f5d23e0cadad2d4158911ef72f095d[...]
```

So the two hashes don’t match.

I am using the following gem: https://github.com/payu-india/payuindia

I appreciate any help as to why the response hash is not matching. Is there any error in my logic to compute the response hash? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this was a silly mistake i made. The reason the hash didn't match was beacuse i had a typo with the PAYU test key. At the end i typed small 'u' when it was 'U'. The library is fine and the logic is right. The error was in my side with using wrong key.

Comment: Hi, did you had to implement the verification yourself? What happens if the status from response is success but hash does not match?

Comment: no the library does it all. the only reason i did it manually is to make sure the library was correct or had bug. but in the end i found that the mistake was i was using wrong key.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you come up with that order for the fields in the array?

Looking at [PayU's Developer FAQ](https://www.payumoney.com/faq-dev-support.html) it seems like the order is the following:

```
key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|||||||||||salt
```

> Please make sure that the hash is calculated in the following format - hashSequence= key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||salt
>
> Please make sure that in the above sequence please use the UDFs which have also been posted to our server. In case you haven't posted any UDFs, the hash sequence should look like this - hashSequence= key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|||||||||||salt.

Keep in mind that when computing the hash even a single character out of place will result in a completely different checksum.

Comment: Paumoney uses two hashes. One is request hash which is the one you have posted. For response hash, the transaction status is also prepended.

Comment: please look here. https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/4.-Server-Side . Under the title Post-Transaction hash sequence:( Mandatory ) you will see that response hash is different.

Comment: @kofhearts ah, apologies. I looked at the code of the gem you've linked in the original post and the number of fields and their order looks correct then.

Comment: The problem is when I post to production payu site then response hash matches with the same above formula but when using test site, it doesn't match. So I wonder the problem is with their test site.

Answer (score 1):

little late but Actual Sequence is:

```
SALT|status||||||udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key
```

Thanks to Ravi Kant Singh

but `additionalCharges|` are removed

Tested with live environment

Check your hash in above order and if its match you can process request

Comment: That does not answer the OPs query. Please consider editing/deleting your response

Answer (score 0):

Actual Sequence for hash is : 
additionalCharges|SALT|status||||||udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key

Answer (score 0):

Actual hash generation for additional charges:

```
additionalCharges|SALT|status||||||udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key
```

Without additional charges:

```
SALT|status||||||udf5|udf4|udf3|udf2|udf1|email|firstname|productinfo|amount|txnid|key
```